# Pinescript Conversion v4 to v5: Existing code works fine, but I can't publish it. Can someone explain it to me?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm trying my best to understand how to convert code form v4 to v5 to create buy and sell alerts. I don't have strong coding background. Can someone help me with this or explain it to me?

In the code below you find the old version, which cannot be used for custom alert messages.

```
//@version=4
study(shorttitle="BBSR Scalping", title="Bollinger Bands Stochastic RSI Scalping", overlay=true, resolution="")

//General Inputs
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(0, "Offset", type = input.integer, minval = -500, maxval = 500)

//Bollinger Inputs
length = input(20, title="Bollinger Band Length", minval=1)
mult = input(2.5, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")

//Bollinger Code
basis = sma(src, length)
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
plot(basis, "BB Basis", color=#872323, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(upper, "BB Upper", color=color.teal, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(lower, "BB Lower", color=color.teal, offset = offset)
fill(p1, p2, title = "BB Background", color=#198787, transp=95)


//Stoch Inputs
smoothK = input(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)

upperlimit = input(80, "Upper Limit", minval=0.01)
lowerlimit = input(20, "Upper Limit", minval=0.01)

//Stochastic Code
rsi1 = rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)

//Evaluation
Bear = close[1] > upper[1] and close < upper
     and k[1] > upperlimit and d[1] > upperlimit
Bull = close[1] < lower[1] and close > lower
     and k[1] < lowerlimit and d[1] < lowerlimit


//Plots
plotshape(Bear, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, 
     color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(Bull, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, 
     color=color.green, size=size.tiny)
 
// Alert Functionality
alertcondition(Bear or Bull, title="Any Signal", message="{{exchange}}:{{ticker}}" + " {{interval}}" + " BBSR Scalping!")
alertcondition(Bear, title="Bearish Signal", message="{{exchange}}:{{ticker}}" + " {{interval}}" + " Bearish BBSR Scalping!")
alertcondition(Bull, title="Bullish Signal", message="{{exchange}}:{{ticker}}" + " {{interval}}" + " Bullish BBSR Scalping!")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

The Pine Script™ Editor includes a utility to automatically convert v4 scripts to v5.

```
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#v4-to-v5-converter
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am unable to use this because...the v4 pinescript I found don't belong to me. But it is similar to what I'd like to get done save for some tweaks here and there. So when I copy that v4 pinescript and paste it into my pinescript editor (which is v5), it won't work. Correct me if I'm wrong, the utility option would appear only if it is MY existing v4 pinescript that needs conversion to v5. So in my case, I do need to do the conversion manually...which is the problem. I can't seem to locate any resource that would tell me how to get that done.

Comment: The conversion utility works with any code you have in your editor.
I just converted your code, and it works perfectly
Test it!